# How do you group an array by n and the number of decreasing integers (n-1)? With the output to be the total number of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, output, group

For example, this is the input array: `[2, 1, 4, 4, 3]`

From this array, *n-1* patterns will be established from left to right.

This output would be the number `7` because the following separate arrays exist after grouping:

`[2] [1] [4] [4] [3]` - 1 group (*n*)

`[4, 3]` - 1 group (*n-1*)

`[2, 1]` - 1 group (*n-1*)

Output: `7` (arrays)

This is what I started so far, but it looks like I just summed everything together.

```js
let numbers = [2, 1, 4, 4, 3];
let sum = numbers.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
});

console.log(sum);
```

It would be appreciated if the solution and an explanation is provided in JavaScript. Thank you!

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your code calculates a sum, but the question doesn't say anything about summing the numbers. I don't understand what you mean by `n and n-1 pattern`

Comment: First group the arrays, and then have an output of the number of arrays

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: What is `n`? Why do the groups have 1 element when you say `n`, but 2 elements when you say `n-1`. Shouldn't that be `n+1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  let numbers = [2, 1, 4, 4, 3];
  // remove duplicates
  let unique = [...new Set(numbers)];
  // get length of unique array, then add to the length of filtered unique array where it also contains n-1
  console.log(unique.length + unique.filter(number => numbers.includes(number - 1)).length);
}
```

Get the number of unique elements then add it to the length of the filtered unique array where it also contains `n-1`.

#### Output:

[image: output]

If you want to get the arrays:

```
function myFunction() {
  let numbers = [2, 1, 4, 4, 3];
  let unique = [...new Set(numbers)];
  var arrays = [];
  unique.forEach(number => {
    arrays.push([number]); 
    if(numbers.includes(number - 1))
      arrays.push([number, number-1])
  });

  console.log(arrays.length)
  console.log(arrays)
}
```

[image: output2]